# Is there a cross-browser way to condense text on a page?

Tags: css, fonts

I am looking for a way to condense relatively small areas of text on a page in an effort to mimic a graphic button that was done with a non-standard font. Ideally, just the letters would get squished or made thinner, leaving the space between words more or less the same. I know there are some CSS attributes that do things like this, but they are more focused on spacing between the letters and not so much on the widths of the letters themselves. These CSS methods are also not very cross-browser friendly. The majority of the user base is using IE6, so that puts a large restriction on CSS-based methods out of the blocks.

So, is there any way to control the character width/spacing that is cross-browser friendly? I know jQuery works across browsers quite well, so could this perhaps be done with jQuery by manipulating the location of the letters and possibly their widths? These are small bits of text, 5 words at a time, or so, so speed is something that can be dealt with later.

---

EDIT: Ok, so, the CSS letter-spacing property, as well as the word-spacing property will allow me to control the space between letters/words. However, this makes things look squished. If this truly is the only option, then I'll have to make it work, but what I am really looking for is a way to squish the letters themselves, to make the characters thinner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** I don't think there is a working cross-browser example that meets your requirements.

The CSS3 specification includes a [`font-stretch`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-stretch) property, but sadly enough, CSS3 is barely (if at all) supported at this time.

Some possible ways that could **emulate** this behaviour that I can think of:

- Use a flash-based approach like [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/)
- Use a javascript / canvas based approach like [Typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/). There's a font-stretch example included on [the example page](http://typeface.neocracy.org/examples.html)
- Use condensed fonts (icky-approach, since this means you are relying on the font being available for the client), like Arial Narrow.
- Use a server-side script that generates an image from text parameters

In short, there is **no simple and elegant solution** to this problem because text and image manipulation is generally something you'd do in a **graphics editor**.

If this is not possible, I'd definately recommend looking into [Typeface](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) and [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/).

Answer (score 11):

maybe

```
letter-spacing:-1px
```

[will help](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp)

Comment: thanks for the negative vote. Maybe you will argument your pick?

Comment: This would be my suggestion. +1

Comment: Cdeszaq already clearly explained that letter-spacing in his question. This answer is simply incorrect as it does not condense the font, but simply decreases the space between the letters.

Comment: Agreed that the OP did say he had tried spacing techniques already, which implies letter-spacing.  However, the original (pre-edit) text was looking for a way to control "character width/spacing", which looks to me like "character width or spacing".

Comment: @aron: cdeszaq explain that in EDIT zone. I post way before that ;) Anyhow, let's not argue on this :)

Comment: Staicu, no personal harm intended ofcourse, but the original post states: "I know there are some CSS attributes that do things like this, but they are more focused on spacing between the letters and not so much on the widths of the letters themselves."

Comment: Well i vote this up - for non-english like me searching  for "condense letters" and getting what was needed :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this sort of thing should probably be done in a graphics editor and output to a lightweight image (png or similar). I think this is the only simple and reliable way to control the visual output of the text to this extent.

Make sure you repeat the text in the **alt** attribute on the **img** tag for accessibility.

This approach has issues with localization - in that you need a version for each locale - but this is still doable.

There are also going to be issues if you wanted to keep this text in-line with some other text - e.g. in the middle of a paragraph. But if that's what is being done, it sounds like "squished up text" may not really be a good UI.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to squish it without squishing it?

Try adjusting the font-size then. Or some combination of letter-spacing, word-spacing and font-size. (All of which work just fine in IE6).

```
.nav {font-size: 80%;
letter-spacing: -.05em;
word-spacing: .05em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're specifying your doctypes properly?  Perhaps your browsers are interpreting your CSS in quirks mode, resulting in the unpredictable behavior.

I don't think jQuery will be of much help to you if `letter-spacing` isn't working properly.  You can't alter the positions of individual letters unless every letter is inside its own element, such as a `span`, which just seems messy.

**EDIT:** If you want to shrink the horizontal width of the characters themselves, that would theoretically be done with `font-stretch: narrower`, for example.   But it seems the major browser don't support it properly or at all.  Apparently it was in CSS2, but then dropped in CSS2.1 and is now planned for CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a nightmare.

You can fudge the whole thing by putting each word if a floated DIV and fiddling with the width each DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to question the wisdom of even trying to do this in the first place.  Just replace the darn graphic with something readable; or something you can duplicate with your text.

What you want to do is change the text's font.  I think your best bet is looking through a bunch of different fonts that come preinstalled for your userbase and trying for the best font+size combo.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to track down the original font with [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Answer (score 0):

Approaching ten years later, `font-stretch` is still virtually unsupported.  But 
`transform:scaleX();` will do. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_scalex).